# Frameset in flex application?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flexbuilder

There is a frameset concept in HTML that we all know.

But I need that to be done in flex application.

How to do that ?

Comment: You need to elaborate. What sort of information would you like to display in Flex? HTML? Images? What makes you think you need framesets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you're after is just a similar GUI component container layout than what you'd get using HTML frames, check out the [`DividedBox`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/containers/DividedBox.html) component (as well as its horizontal and vertical subclasses, `HDividedBox` and `VDividedBox`.) You can use the [Flex 3 Style Explorer](http://examples.adobe.com/flex3/consulting/styleexplorer/Flex3StyleExplorer.html#) to see what they look and feel like. You can nest them inside each other just like with framesets.

Comment: Combine the DividedBox with a ViewStack, and you'll even be able to work with a page-like concept.